# Why is my SQL "INSERT INTO" query not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, crud

I'm making a storage log for work, and I've been fighting with this code for the last two hours with no success. For some reason, no matter how many times I check and recheck the code for my INSERT INTO query, it will not work.

Keep in mind that I copied this code, almost verbatim (changed the form names and fields, obviously) from another page that has basically the same functionality and works 100%. Code below:

This is the page containing the form where the transaction is being submitted:

```
<?php
$script = '<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
}); </script>' ; 
$title = "View/Edit Storage - " ;
include('inc/header.php'); 
?>
<table>
                <tr>
                <form action="transadded.php" name='addnewtransaction' method="POST">
                    <td><input type="text" name="moveID" size="20" value="<?php echo $results[moveid]; ?>" readonly> </td>
                    <td><select id="inoutselect" name="inorout">
                            <option value="Select">Select</option>
                            <option value="Storage In">Storage In</option>
                            <option value="Storage Out">Storage Out</option>
                        </select> </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="numberofunits" size="20"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="dateoftransaction" size="20" class="datepicker"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="rrdt" size="20"> </td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Add" id="logsubmit"></td>
                </form>
                </table>
                <br /><br />
<?php   };?>
```

Here's the query itself, aka "transadded.php":

```
<?php
$title = "Project Added - ";
include('inc/header.php');
$query = "INSERT INTO newtransaction (moveid, inout, units, transdate, refno) VALUES('$_POST[moveID]','$_POST[inorout]','$_POST[numberofunits]','$_POST[dateoftransaction]','$_POST[rrdt]')";

if(!mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo '<div class="transstatus">' . '1 record added' . '</div>';

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The header, obviously, contains the function for connecting to the database, and as I said, another query works just fine with it, so I know that that isn't the problem. Upon clicking the submit button, the error I get on the page is as follows:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inout, units, transdate, refno) VALUES ('1234567','Storage In','81','09/11/2013'' at line 1

Here, "1234567", "Storage In", etc are the values I enter into the form.

I hope you can help me out. I'm so stuck!

Also, I know that I'm not protected against injection right now. I plan to work on that later, but I'm trying to get the functionality straightened out first.

Comment: What's the sense of mysqli if not prepared statements?

Comment: What does the table structure look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

INOUT is a MySQL reserved word.

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Change the name or put it in quotes.

Comment: Wow. I am the worst. That did it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Foo hehe, and I thought I knew all the reserved words off the top of my head. Nice pickup. +1

Comment: It gets everyone -- I'm no MySQL expert, and pulled my hair out over a similar issue. Glad it's working now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO newtransaction (
         `moveid`, `inout`, `units`, `transdate`, `refno`
    )
    VALUES(
        '{$_POST[moveID]}', '{$_POST[inorout]}',
        '{$_POST[numberofunits]}', '{$_POST[dateoftransaction]}',
        '{$_POST[rrdt]}'
    )
";
```

Comment: The OP mentioned it, but I'd be inclined to add a note to the question to say that the SQL injection vuln must be fixed, so as not to have someone use it without fully reading the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO newtransaction (moveid, inout, units, transdate, refno) 
VALUES
( '".$_POST['moveID']."','".$_POST['inorout']."','".$_POST['numberofunits']."',
   '".$_POST['dateoftransaction']."','".$_POST['rrdt']."')";
```

you post your like `='$_POST[dateoftransaction]'`

right procedure is if you using wamp`= '".$_POST['dateoftransaction']."'`

i hope you got your mistake

Ferrakkem